# Django ChoiceField - How to show the currently selected value?

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I have a Django ChoiceField called `states` defined in my forms class.

```
class StateForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['states'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select,
                                 choices=OPTIONS_STATE)
        self.initial['states'] = 'Any'
```

I also set the initial value to 'Any', since I want the dropdown say 'Any' by default.

In my `views.py`, `get_context_data()` function, I add it to the context that's sent to the html.

```
        context['state_form'] = StateForm()
```

In my html, I can render the dropdown using Django's special language

```
{{ state_form.states }}
```

So far so good. I see a dropdown in my page, and the default value is 'Any'. I can click on it to select other values, at that point my javascript code would send a HTTP request based on my form. It would reload the page with filtered data. I was able to get all of that done.

The problem is that once the page reloads, the dropdown still says 'Any'. I want the dropdown to show the previously selected data. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: Since you passes the selected value back to your views, why don't you do `context['state_form'] = StateForm(initial={'states': dropdown_value})`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand you to store that value in session/cookie and then in javascript change the default value of the dropdown based on that session/cookie information.

More about cookies you can find in django doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to a new URL, pass the selected state as a GET parameter to the URL. Eg:

```
url = 'http://example.com/some-page/?state=Texas'
```

Then on the next page, use JS to read the `state` parameter and set the value of the dropdown accordingly. Or you can pass the `state` as context variable in the next URL's view.